# How can I display the "timestamp" for each form?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I have 3 forms, each form has a timestamp, I want to display the timestamp for each form, I made a method that displays the timestamp for first form, but I want all timestamps from all forms, I use indexedDB.

I made a method that displays the timestamp for first form.

```
this.DataBaseService.findInTableNameByColumnName('forms', 'by_formName', 'user-creation-form').then( (result: any) => {
     let see = result.timestamp;
     console.log(see);
});
```

I want to display the timestamp for each form.

Comment: Try moment package

Comment: I am guessing the `user-creation-form` you are passing is the name of your first form? If yes, then can you make the form name a parameter and have your from component call it for each form?

Comment: Hi guys, I fixed it, I used map().